# An equation which has solution modulo every integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, congruences

In the book Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote he remarks that there is an equation which has solutions modulo every integer but has no integer solutions. The equation he gives is $$3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$$My question is how do we prove that this has solutions modulo every integer and also that it has no integer solutions? If anyone can give hints it would be great.

Comment: See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47442/diophantine-equation-with-no-integer-solutions-but-with-solutions-modulo-every

Comment: In short, the simplest proof involves unique factorization in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{6})$.  But there are much easier examples of this property, such as the equation $(X^2-2)(X^2-17)(X^2-34)=0$.

Comment: @Slade I think the equation you mention is also better example of this since the equation from D&F has always the trivial solution $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @PavelC I think this distinction mostly disappears with homogenization/dehomogenization.  I think that the cubic equation is somehow a higher-quality example, because it is irreducible and nonsingular as a projective variety, but this quadratic approach is certainly much easier to understand from an elementary perspective.

Comment: @Slade thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another
$$  x^2 + y^2 + z^9 = 216,   $$ where we allow $z$ negative or positive or zero as desired. Same conclusion for
$$  x^2 + y^2 + z^9 = 216 p^3,   $$ with prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$

See [PDF](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Experimental_1995.pdf)